# An issue in R Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = attr(object, : factor

Tags: r

NOTE: I tried looking at other similar issues and I couldn't resolve it.

I'm a bit new to this environment and I'm following along with a pre-done model. However, I ran into an issue at the latter of the analysis.
The error is as it follows:
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = attr(object,  :
factor Audience_country has new levels Albania, China, Poland, Ukraine

The way I split my data is in 0.7 ratio. I have data that contains countries and my guess is when it's split the training and test data, some values were not transferred. Any way I can resolve this issue?

NOTE: At some point (at the beginning of this analysis) I also separate the data (however, I keep using the same data throughout the whole analysis) -- That is the InstaDate variable.

```
InstaDate = InstagramDate <- select(InstagramDate, category_1:Engagement_avg)


set.seed(123)
insta_split <- initial_split(InstaDate, prop = 0.7)
insta_train <- training(insta_split)
insta_test <- testing(insta_split)
```

Where I get the error:

```
  optimal_tree <- rpart(
  formula = Followers ~ .,
  data = insta_train,
  method = "anova",
  control = list(minsplit = 11, maxdepth = 12, cp = 0.01000000)
)

pred <- predict(m1, newdata = insta_test) <--- ERROR!
RMSE(pred = pred, obs = insta_test$Followers)
optimal_tree
```

Again, I'm very new at this, don't judge me.

Comment: You're probably right that the problem is caused by some factor levels in `Audidence_country` that only shows up in the test-data. This is quite a typical problem for machine learning. My recommendation would be to use the [`recipes` package](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/) for preprocessing your data. This problem can be solved with `step_novel()`, `step_other()`, or similar steps.

Comment: Can you give me any hints as to how I may do that?

Comment: There are many hints in the link I shared, but I have also included an example in my answer to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typical to get this error when the test data has categories that does not exists in the training data.

There are many ways of handling this. Under, I show how we can use `recpes` to turn all novel categories into `NA` values.

```r
library(rsample)
library(rpart)
library(recipes)
set.seed(123)

# I'll use mtcars as an example, but I'll add a new categorical column
data <- mtcars
data$var <- sample(c("A", "B"), size = 32, replace = TRUE)

# Split the data
split <- initial_split(data, prop = 0.7)
train <- training(split)
test  <- testing(split)

# Add a new factor level to var just for the training data
test$var[1] <- "C"

# Build the model
model <- rpart(
  formula = mpg ~ .,
  data = train
)

# Error due to the novel factor level
predict(model, newdata = test)
#> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = attr(object, : factor var has new levels C



# Fixing this with recipes ------------------------------------------------

# Create a recipe that handles novel levels in var
rec <- 
  recipe(mpg ~ ., data = train) %>% 
  step_other(var) %>% # This is where we handle new categories
  prep()

new_train <- bake(rec, new_data = train)
new_test  <- bake(rec, new_data = test)

# We build the model again with the prepared data
model <- rpart(
  formula = mpg ~ .,
  data = new_train
)

# This works
predict(model, newdata = new_test)
#>        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
#> 25.61000 25.61000 25.61000 25.61000 15.64167 15.64167 15.64167 25.61000 
#>        9       10 
#> 25.61000 15.64167
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

An alternative to `step_other()` would be `step_novel()`.

Comment: Bless you! This should help!

Comment: Hey! I got the following error
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `Spain`, `Indonesia`, `Russia`, `Indonesia`, `Indonesia`, etc. don't exist.
There seems to be values that are again missing... :s

Comment: It’s hard to help you when I don’t see your code. The error message suggest that you have a column for each country, and maybe these differ between train and test. Did you use `step_dummy()` or similar by any chance?

Comment: I did not. However, I grouped the countries by continents and now it works! Thanks for your efforts in helping me!