# R: Trying to understand the "Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels)"

Tags: r, linear-regression

So, I was trying to plot the predicted values of a regression model w/ a quadratic term:

```
model <- lm(y ~ x1 + poly(x2, 2) + x3 + as.factor(x4) + as.factor(x5), data = data)

jtools::effect_plot(model, pred = x2)
```

But I got the following error:

```
`Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor as.factor(x4) has new level 0.43`
```

I understand (based on these questions: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784594/error-in-model-frame-defaultterms-newdata-na-action-na-action-xlev-objec) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72367400/an-issue-in-r-error-in-model-frame-defaultterms-newdata-na-action-na-action)) that this error comes from a level in my factor variable *x4* that is not present/represented in my original data (and I also know that these two questions offer some way to "fix" or circumvent it).

However, when I tried to change X4 and X5's classes before running the model, it worked fine:

```
data$x4 <- as.factor(data$x4)
data$x5 <- as.factor(data$x5)

model2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + poly(x2, 2) + x3 + x4 + x5, data = data)

jtools::effect_plot(model2, pred = x2)
```

My question is: **Why does this happen?**

Thanks in advance :)

Data for reproduction:

```
data <- structure(list(y = c(3.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 
5, 3.33333333333333, 3, 3.33333333333333, 3, 3, 3.33333333333333, 
4.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 3, 1.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
2.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 3, 3, 3, 3.33333333333333, 
3, 3.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333), x1 = c(5L, 
2L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 9L), x2 = c(0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), x3 = c(37L, 
40L, 41L, 72L, 71L, 37L, 70L, 43L, 37L, 55L, 30L, 38L, 54L, 55L, 
62L, 80L, 80L, 24L, 73L, 72L, 50L, 66L, 41L, 46L, 66L), x4 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), x5 = c(4L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 
4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 
4L, 8L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`31` = 31L, `46` = 46L, 
`62` = 62L, `90` = 90L, `99` = 99L, `129` = 129L, `156` = 156L, 
`165` = 165L, `187` = 187L, `201` = 201L, `219` = 219L, `228` = 228L, 
`257` = 257L, `261` = 261L, `312` = 312L, `318` = 318L, `319` = 319L, 
`328` = 328L, `340` = 340L, `343` = 343L, `345` = 345L, `354` = 354L, 
`356` = 356L, `376` = 376L, `417` = 417L, `421` = 421L, `439` = 439L, 
`448` = 448L, `464` = 464L, `492` = 492L, `525` = 525L, `526` = 526L, 
`527` = 527L, `528` = 528L, `535` = 535L, `536` = 536L, `541` = 541L, 
`601` = 601L, `613` = 613L, `638` = 638L, `644` = 644L, `688` = 688L, 
`726` = 726L, `754` = 754L, `767` = 767L, `787` = 787L, `796` = 796L, 
`813` = 813L, `835` = 835L, `853` = 853L, `868` = 868L, `924` = 924L, 
`927` = 927L, `930` = 930L, `932` = 932L, `944` = 944L, `990` = 990L, 
`1008` = 1008L, `1050` = 1050L, `1069` = 1069L, `1091` = 1091L, 
`1100` = 1100L, `1120` = 1120L, `1172` = 1172L, `1184` = 1184L, 
`1192` = 1192L, `1203` = 1203L, `1206` = 1206L, `1222` = 1222L, 
`1241` = 1241L, `1245` = 1245L, `1259` = 1259L, `1293` = 1293L, 
`1298` = 1298L, `1312` = 1312L, `1313` = 1313L, `1330` = 1330L, 
`1368` = 1368L, `1397` = 1397L, `1411` = 1411L, `1427` = 1427L, 
`1438` = 1438L, `1443` = 1443L, `1460` = 1460L, `1464` = 1464L, 
`1489` = 1489L, `1511` = 1511L, `1526` = 1526L, `1566` = 1566L, 
`1577` = 1577L, `1578` = 1578L, `1604` = 1604L, `1619` = 1619L, 
`1627` = 1627L, `1642` = 1642L, `1645` = 1645L, `1654` = 1654L, 
`1672` = 1672L, `1728` = 1728L, `1752` = 1752L, `1794` = 1794L, 
`1800` = 1800L, `1813` = 1813L, `1815` = 1815L, `1831` = 1831L, 
`1837` = 1837L, `1850` = 1850L, `1883` = 1883L, `1902` = 1902L, 
`1905` = 1905L, `1939` = 1939L, `2000` = 2000L, `2026` = 2026L, 
`2035` = 2035L, `2040` = 2040L, `2072` = 2072L, `2076` = 2076L, 
`2090` = 2090L, `2101` = 2101L, `2112` = 2112L, `2121` = 2121L, 
`2140` = 2140L, `2142` = 2142L, `2143` = 2143L, `2177` = 2177L, 
`2224` = 2224L, `2243` = 2243L, `2255` = 2255L, `2258` = 2258L, 
`2262` = 2262L, `2271` = 2271L, `2279` = 2279L, `2281` = 2281L, 
`2286` = 2286L, `2290` = 2290L, `2302` = 2302L, `2315` = 2315L, 
`2331` = 2331L, `2345` = 2345L, `2348` = 2348L, `2349` = 2349L, 
`2355` = 2355L, `2357` = 2357L, `2375` = 2375L, `2388` = 2388L, 
`2394` = 2394L, `2409` = 2409L, `2444` = 2444L, `2452` = 2452L, 
`2458` = 2458L, `2465` = 2465L, `2468` = 2468L, `2484` = 2484L, 
`2506` = 2506L, `2509` = 2509L, `2512` = 2512L, `2516` = 2516L, 
`2567` = 2567L, `2571` = 2571L, `2583` = 2583L, `2589` = 2589L, 
`2625` = 2625L, `2644` = 2644L, `2660` = 2660L, `2690` = 2690L, 
`2706` = 2706L, `2717` = 2717L, `2729` = 2729L, `2732` = 2732L, 
`2749` = 2749L, `2751` = 2751L, `2776` = 2776L, `2835` = 2835L, 
`2838` = 2838L, `2841` = 2841L, `2852` = 2852L, `2893` = 2893L, 
`2895` = 2895L, `2896` = 2896L, `2909` = 2909L, `2910` = 2910L, 
`2923` = 2923L, `2934` = 2934L, `2945` = 2945L, `2947` = 2947L, 
`2961` = 2961L, `2985` = 2985L, `3001` = 3001L, `3012` = 3012L, 
`3020` = 3020L, `3028` = 3028L, `3049` = 3049L, `3053` = 3053L, 
`3069` = 3069L, `3083` = 3083L, `3119` = 3119L, `3129` = 3129L, 
`3170` = 3170L, `3175` = 3175L, `3179` = 3179L, `3186` = 3186L, 
`3193` = 3193L, `3198` = 3198L, `3200` = 3200L, `3203` = 3203L, 
`3205` = 3205L, `3208` = 3208L, `3225` = 3225L, `3235` = 3235L, 
`3255` = 3255L, `3264` = 3264L, `3270` = 3270L, `3276` = 3276L, 
`3285` = 3285L, `3300` = 3300L, `3304` = 3304L, `3326` = 3326L, 
`3339` = 3339L, `3341` = 3341L, `3350` = 3350L, `3378` = 3378L, 
`3382` = 3382L, `3388` = 3388L, `3401` = 3401L, `3414` = 3414L, 
`3417` = 3417L, `3454` = 3454L, `3458` = 3458L, `3497` = 3497L, 
`3510` = 3510L, `3515` = 3515L, `3519` = 3519L, `3534` = 3534L, 
`3604` = 3604L, `3612` = 3612L, `3616` = 3616L, `3618` = 3618L, 
`3654` = 3654L, `3675` = 3675L, `3680` = 3680L, `3685` = 3685L, 
`3691` = 3691L, `3693` = 3693L, `3698` = 3698L, `3716` = 3716L, 
`3718` = 3718L, `3742` = 3742L, `3759` = 3759L, `3789` = 3789L, 
`3795` = 3795L, `3802` = 3802L, `3809` = 3809L, `3810` = 3810L, 
`3836` = 3836L, `3853` = 3853L, `3884` = 3884L, `3896` = 3896L, 
`3909` = 3909L, `3925` = 3925L, `3937` = 3937L, `3949` = 3949L, 
`3999` = 3999L, `4015` = 4015L, `4022` = 4022L, `4036` = 4036L, 
`4051` = 4051L, `4060` = 4060L, `4082` = 4082L, `4086` = 4086L, 
`4098` = 4098L, `4108` = 4108L, `4109` = 4109L, `4125` = 4125L, 
`4129` = 4129L, `4139` = 4139L, `4180` = 4180L, `4184` = 4184L, 
`4207` = 4207L, `4209` = 4209L, `4223` = 4223L, `4238` = 4238L, 
`4246` = 4246L, `4249` = 4249L, `4253` = 4253L, `4264` = 4264L, 
`4265` = 4265L, `4286` = 4286L, `4290` = 4290L, `4301` = 4301L, 
`4317` = 4317L, `4329` = 4329L, `4340` = 4340L, `4343` = 4343L, 
`4345` = 4345L, `4384` = 4384L, `4438` = 4438L, `4442` = 4442L, 
`4450` = 4450L, `4467` = 4467L, `4469` = 4469L, `4474` = 4474L, 
`4479` = 4479L, `4481` = 4481L, `4482` = 4482L, `4490` = 4490L, 
`4509` = 4509L, `4512` = 4512L, `4522` = 4522L, `4526` = 4526L, 
`4536` = 4536L, `4545` = 4545L, `4568` = 4568L, `4572` = 4572L, 
`4581` = 4581L, `4586` = 4586L, `4588` = 4588L, `4610` = 4610L, 
`4612` = 4612L, `4618` = 4618L, `4660` = 4660L, `4663` = 4663L, 
`4667` = 4667L, `4678` = 4678L, `4680` = 4680L, `4712` = 4712L, 
`4721` = 4721L, `4725` = 4725L, `4740` = 4740L, `4763` = 4763L, 
`4768` = 4768L, `4771` = 4771L, `4788` = 4788L, `4793` = 4793L, 
`4797` = 4797L, `4805` = 4805L, `4816` = 4816L, `4821` = 4821L, 
`4822` = 4822L, `4840` = 4840L, `4845` = 4845L, `4861` = 4861L, 
`4878` = 4878L, `4883` = 4883L, `4893` = 4893L, `4896` = 4896L, 
`4898` = 4898L, `4902` = 4902L, `4950` = 4950L, `4978` = 4978L, 
`5005` = 5005L, `5016` = 5016L, `5027` = 5027L, `5036` = 5036L, 
`5045` = 5045L, `5064` = 5064L, `5073` = 5073L, `5088` = 5088L, 
`5089` = 5089L, `5094` = 5094L, `5129` = 5129L, `5153` = 5153L, 
`5162` = 5162L, `5175` = 5175L, `5199` = 5199L, `5209` = 5209L, 
`5216` = 5216L, `5222` = 5222L, `5228` = 5228L, `5277` = 5277L, 
`5286` = 5286L, `5299` = 5299L, `5301` = 5301L, `5304` = 5304L, 
`5317` = 5317L, `5332` = 5332L, `5335` = 5335L, `5340` = 5340L, 
`5363` = 5363L, `5366` = 5366L, `5380` = 5380L, `5382` = 5382L, 
`5391` = 5391L, `5416` = 5416L, `5423` = 5423L, `5424` = 5424L, 
`5452` = 5452L, `5491` = 5491L, `5494` = 5494L, `5505` = 5505L, 
`5514` = 5514L, `5529` = 5529L, `5547` = 5547L, `5560` = 5560L, 
`5579` = 5579L, `5584` = 5584L, `5594` = 5594L, `5598` = 5598L, 
`5601` = 5601L, `5608` = 5608L, `5609` = 5609L, `5639` = 5639L, 
`5644` = 5644L, `5697` = 5697L, `5703` = 5703L, `5718` = 5718L, 
`5725` = 5725L, `5732` = 5732L, `5773` = 5773L, `5792` = 5792L, 
`5811` = 5811L, `5833` = 5833L, `5864` = 5864L, `5869` = 5869L, 
`5895` = 5895L, `5908` = 5908L, `5915` = 5915L, `5923` = 5923L, 
`5942` = 5942L, `5954` = 5954L, `6028` = 6028L, `6029` = 6029L, 
`6062` = 6062L, `6063` = 6063L, `6072` = 6072L, `6096` = 6096L, 
`6112` = 6112L, `6124` = 6124L, `6139` = 6139L), class = "omit"))
```